# Jar files required to Invoke Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jar, jamvm

I have ported jamvm to my armel device. I am able to run various swing based and communicate to other systems via socket programming method. But when I try to call a webservice I get many NoClassDefFound exceptions.

I placed jaxws-api.jar file to remove some such exceptions which directed me to other class definition not found exceptions.

Can someone please tell which arfe all the necessary jar files are required to be present during runtime in order to invoke a webservice on a server machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using net beans IDE to develop the restful service it is very essay. Just follow [these](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) instructions all library (including Jersey) will be added to your project. If you need to get the library separated take the lib folder in project path.
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

p.s : You don't need to create DB though.